# Como pedir ao usuário para digitar o tamanho do vetor?

Tags: c

Estou apenas utilizando vetores com um número definido usando o define ou mesmo direto na variável. Como eu coloco  a quantidade de vetores que o usuário escolher?.

exemplo:

```
    #define NUMERO x

    int main()
    {
    int valor[NUMERO];
```

Quero que esse x seja um número que o usuário possa digitar(escolher) no inicio do programa.

Comment: Alguma dificuldade específica? Sabe usar o `scanf()`?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &x);` e depois define o `int valor[x]`

Comment: @FábioMorais e no caso se eu definir usando define , como escolheria um valor para ele? para facilitar manutenção do código?

Comment: (editei a pergunta para melhor visualização)

Comment: O que fez nao fez sentido, `#define NUMERO 10`

Comment: Em uma média , eu quero que calcule 10 números , tenho que dizer ao vetor que quero 10 certo? , tentei jogar no scanf mas não estou conseguindo:

Comment: Acho que a questão se resume a "como ler um numero em C?" ou não percebi a pergunta ?

Comment: @Isac não,  antes fosse isso , eu quero definir uma quantidade que o usuário escolha para o vetor  , tentei usar o scanf e jogar para o vetor e não consegui.

Comment: Então você já cria um vetor com um tamanho especifico `int valor[NUMERO];` Se sabe ler um numero é so colocar a variavel que leu onde está `NUMERO`. Talvez seja confusão sobre a sintaxe de criação de vetor não ? Que talvez ainda não tenha percebido completamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(){
    int x=10;
    int valor[x];
}
```

É a mesma coisa que fazer

```
int main(){
    int valor[10];
}
```

---

**Ou usando `define`**

```
// #define x ValorPredefinido 
#define x 10 /** EXEMPLO, caso saiba que será esse valor **/ 

int main(){
    int valor[x];
}
```

---

**A partir dos códigos abaixo não sabemos a quantidade que será preciso à partida.**

```
int main(){
    int x;
    printf("Qual o tamanho do vetor?"); 
    scanf("%d", &x); /** caso seja um valor que o usuário terá de colocar**/
    int valor[x];
}
```

---

Uma outra opção é usar memoria dinâmica.

```
int main(){
  int *valor;
}
```

Ir alocando memória à medida que precisa de mais espaço.

---

- O que não pode é fazer `int valor[x]` sem ter um valor, nos exemplos
  acima quando chega a essa linha `x` **vai ter um valor**

Comment: Então o primeiro código não é possível alterar a quantidade do valor digitado no define , o segundo no caso de eu digitar 10 por exemplo a variável x fica x[10] então?

Comment: Exatamente, no define o valor fica definido para o programa completo

Comment: Muito obrigado , o meu professor falou que não era possível que o usuário digitasse a quantidade do vetor que queria , acho que ele está errado rsrs

Comment: Quando aprendi C tambem me disseram isso, o que não pode é definir com um `x` sem dar valor nenhum, os exemplos que dei acaba sempre por ter um valor

Comment: A partir do C99  é possivel inicializar vetores com um variáveis

Comment: Inicializar um vetor sem dar um valor à variavel previamente? Não faz sentido, para isso serve a memoria dinâmica. Se inicializarmos como `int numero[x]` o compilador nao vai saber a memoria que vai precisar, agora se for como citei nos exemplos acima já vai saber.